# Turning a string into a list of numbers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

After running an SQL query I get a data frame with one column that looks like this:

```
d = {'values': ['2,3,2,2', '2,3,5', '2', '3,4,2,2,2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

What I need to do is turn each of this strings into a list of numbers:

```
d = {'values': [[2, 3, 2, 2], [2, 3, 5], [2], [3, 4, 2, 2, 2]]}
```

Is there a pythonic way to do that?

Comment: expected output is new column or dictionary ?

Comment: A new column in the same data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way using `pd.eval` and `explode`

Hat tip to Jezrael (for the eval thread) and cs95 (for the pd.Eval tip) in the comments, read :

[Why using eval is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

```
df['values_agg'] = df['values'].map(pd.eval)

print(df)

      values       values_agg
0    2,3,2,2     [2, 3, 2, 2]
1      2,3,5        [2, 3, 5]
2          2              [2]
3  3,4,2,2,2  [3, 4, 2, 2, 2]
```

or avoiding eval all together in a more verbose way.

```
df['values'].str.split(',').explode().astype(int).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Comment: [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) ?

Comment: Here is better use `astype(int)` after `explode`

Comment: Change `eval` to `pd.eval` and you are good — you won't even need the typecast

Comment: @jezrael wow, that is very informative but I think it's more in-tune for applications I could change it to `str.split` then `explode.astype(int)` I guess ?

Comment: yop, exactly need this way.

Comment: no I mean `df['values'].map(pd.eval)`, you don't need the other stuff. The 3rd row will remain a scalar instead of a list, big deal.

Comment: @cs95 gracias mes ami, wow that's amazing didn't know that. thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Using `pandas.Series.str.findall`:

```
df["values"] = df["values"].str.findall("\d+")
d2 = df.to_dict("list")
print(d2)
```

Output:

```
{'values': [['2', '3', '2', '2'], 
            ['2', '3', '5'], 
            ['2'], 
            ['3', '4', '2', '2', '2']]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because need numbers after split comvert values to integers:

```
df['values'] = df['values'].apply(lambda x: [int(y) for y in x.split(',')])
print (df)
            values
0     [2, 3, 2, 2]
1        [2, 3, 5]
2              [2]
3  [3, 4, 2, 2, 2]


print (df.to_dict("l"))
{'values': [[2, 3, 2, 2], [2, 3, 5], [2], [3, 4, 2, 2, 2]]}
```

For strings repr of numbers solution is simplier, only use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['values'] = df['values'].str.split(',')
print (df.to_dict("l"))
{'values': [['2', '3', '2', '2'], ['2', '3', '5'], ['2'], ['3', '4', '2', '2', '2']]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do with a list comprehension:

```
d = {'values': [list(map(int, x.split(','))) for x in df['values']]}
```

[out]

```
{'values': [[2, 3, 2, 2], [2, 3, 5], [2], [3, 4, 2, 2, 2]]}
```